# DB Error: extension not found

Tags: joomla, php

I'm running CiviCRM 5.63.1 on a Joomla 4 environment and using PHP 8.0.28.

cli.php keeps failing with these errors:

[code] => -25
[message] => DB Error: extension not found
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] =>  [DB Error: extension not found]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] =>  [DB Error: extension not found]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: extension not found" code=-25 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [DB Error: extension not found]"]

Looking at the logs I can see where the error gets thrown and it seems to be in PEAR.php

Aug 14 17:10:43  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(249): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(945): CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: extension not found", -25, 16, (Array:2), " [DB Error: extension not found]")
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-25, 16, (Array:2), " [DB Error: extension not found]")
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysql), NULL, -25, 16, (Array:2), " [DB Error: extension not found]", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysql.php(202): DB_common->raiseError(-25)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.org/httpdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(571): DB_mysql->connect((Array:10), FALSE)

Any clues?

I found an old post where it was suggested that changing the connect string to mysqli fixed it, tried that but it didn't.

Is this an incompatibility between PHP 8 and Pear? Are there any other connection methods I can try.

Thanks

Comment: Is mysqli actually enabled in php (does it appear in the output of `php -i`)?

Comment: That was a really interesting question and the answer was no! I added mysql to my PHP environment and that seems to have fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments the problem was that mysqli was not enabled in php.